# Implementing subscript text within regular text (math equation)

Tags: math-mode, text-decorations

How do you add subscript text within a text string e.g. I would like my the output to have the max as subscript

```
\text{AC generator emf_max}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). For future reference, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that sets up the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: How about `$\text{AC generator } \mathrm{emf}_\mathrm{max}$`.  I assumed you were already in math mode as you are using `\text{}`.

Comment: or `\text{AC generator }emf_{\max}`

Comment: @Peter Grill  Thank you for your responses, the reason for lack of formatting is that I am performing this within Pages which supports quick latex functionality without the use of document formatting and declarations. Your answer works though I moved all text into the `mathrm{}` for consistency. Thank you for your answers and I would upvote your comment if I had enough reputation to do so.

Comment: In `\mathrm` you won't have spaces.

Comment: @Skillmon I have found that you can use `\;` within `\mathrm{}` to create a space. e.g. `\mathrm{AC \; generator \; emf}_\mathrm{max} = 2N \ell v B= 2\pi N B A_{\bot} f`

Comment: It's still a semantic difference though. Also a space would be `~`, not `\;`, I think `\;` was 3/4 of a space (could be wrong here).

Comment: @Skillmon I think you're correct, `\;` does the job although `~` appears much more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

To create subscript text `mathrm` can be used, in relation to the example above; `mathrm` would be implemented as:

```
\mathrm{AC ~ generator ~ emf}_\mathrm{max}
```

(with use of `~` as a space as `mathrm` does not support native spaces.